# (Javascript) Make every second word in a sentence uppercase

Tags: javascript

As the title says, i need to make a function that would make every second word in a sentence uppercase, but do not touch other words. I have this function :
(The first if is in a case there is only one word)

And it does its job, however with a sentence like this "ThIs iS A seNteNCe" it returns "this IS a SENTENCE", whereas i need "ThIs IS a SENTENCE".

```js
function largeLetters(sentence) {
  return sentence.map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? v.toLowerCase() : v.toUpperCase()).join(' ');
}

function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
  sentence = sentence.split(' ');
  if (sentence.length == 1) {
    sentence = sentence.toString().toUpperCase();
    return sentence;
  } else {
    return largeLetters(sentence)
  };
};

console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs iS A seNteNCe"))
```

Comment: `v.toLowerCase()` -> `v` - just don't lowercase the words.

Comment: The title says Make every second word in a sentence uppercase but in your example (ThIs IS a SENTENCE) both second and fourth word is changed to uppercase

Comment: I know this is the case, however im fairly new and the code does not work without it.

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: As @VLAZ said, just do not touch the words with odd index, so map it to itself i.e `v` instead of `v.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji yes, that is what "every second" means - second, fourth, sixth, eighth, tenth, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ: So every first would mean every word?

Comment: Question: are you sure that it's every even word (second, fourth, sixth) you want uppercased, and not ever odd word (first, third, fifth)?  odd words would fit better with the rule for sentences with one word...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've simplified your program a bit.

The problem was in this part:

`i % 2 == 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase()`

you don't need to change every other word to lowercase,
you just leave it as it is:

`i % 2 == 0 ? word : word.toUpperCase()`

```js
function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
 return sentence
   .split(' ')
   .map((word, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? word : word.toUpperCase())
   .join(' ');
};
console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs"))
console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs iS"))
console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs iS A"))
console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs iS A seNteNCe"))
```

Comment: That would be my preferred variant. Since you already had it, I took the long way. Nice!

Comment: Same as Maik Lowrey, you dont have good result if you have only one word in your sentence (must be return an uppercase)

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> that would make every second word in a sentence uppercase

If you mean 'even value' so use `value % 2 === 0` else just change the 2nd value of your array.

Update even words :

```
function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  if(words.length >= 2) {
    return words.map((v,i) => i % 2 === 0 ? v : v.toUpperCase()).join(' ');
  } else { 
    return sentence.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Only update 2nd word :

```
function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  if(words.length >= 2) {
    words[1] = words[1].toUpperCase();
  } else { 
    return sentence.toUpperCase();
  }
  return words.join(' ');
}
```

You can 'minify' it by using a ternary and map

```
function sentenceToUpperCaseMinify(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  return words.length >= 2 ? words.map((v, i) => i === 1 ? v.toUpperCase() : v).join(' ') : sentence.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a ternary if `(condition ? true : false)` and inside it you're calling `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`, meaning that everything that pass through this if will be transformed to *lowercase* or *uppercase*.

```js
sentence.map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? v.toLowerCase() : v.toUpperCase())
```

This means:

```js
if (i % 2 == 0) {
  v.toLowerCase();
else {
  v.toUpperCase();
}
```

So if you wanna only work with the even parts and keep the odd parts untouched you don't need to call `v.toLowerCase()`.

```js
function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
  let parts = sentence.split(" ");
  
  return parts.map((part, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? part : part.toUpperCase()).join(" ");
}

sentence = "ThIs iS A SenTenCe with BoTh Upper and LoWer cases"


console.log(sentenceToUpperCase(sentence));
// ThIs IS A SENTENCE with BOTH Upper AND LoWer CASES
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
i % 2 == 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase()
```

To

```
i % 2 == 0 ? word : word.toUpperCase()
```

```js
function largeLetters(sentence) {
  return sentence.map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? v : v.toUpperCase()).join(' ');
}

function sentenceToUpperCase(sentence) {
  sentence = sentence.split(' ');
  if (sentence.length == 1) {
    sentence = sentence.toString().toUpperCase();
    return sentence;
  } else {
    return largeLetters(sentence)
  };
};

console.log(sentenceToUpperCase("ThIs iS A seNteNCe"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool question and in JS you have many ways to do that. The functions I have used are: lowercase, split, toUpperCase, join. I wrapped in a function.

```js
const str = "this IS a SENTENCE"

function build(str) {
  const s = str.split(' ');  
  // or use (str.toLowerCase()).split(' ') if every odd word have to be lowercase
  let r = [];
  let i = 0;

  s.forEach((e) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      r.push(e)          
    } else {
      r.push(e.toUpperCase())
    }
    i++;
    })
  return r.join(' ');
}

console.log('new Sentense: ', build(str) );
```

Comment: Carefull `i % 2` only return odds. You must be `i % 2 === 0` for evens. And you dont give good answer if the `str` have only one word (must be Uppercase result).

Comment: @AdrienVillalonga I updated my answear. Good advise!